# Send push with parse to certain device?

Tags: android, ios, push, parse-platform, device

I've just gone through this (very good) tutorial: https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications
and only one question is left. Can I send a push-message within my app to only one certain device (probably with the `device token`?) instead of to every device? I don't necessarily need to know how now, a simple "yes, that's possible with parse" or "no, you can't use parse for that" will be enough!

Cheers

Comment: I found that, May it help any one else ..
You can use deviceToken to do that .. http://blog.parse.com/2012/07/23/targeting-pushes-from-a-device/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. There are various ways, you can use device tokens or subscribed channel or even based on any other column in the installation object.

For a start, you can use the Push Composer option provided by Parse.

Checkout these for more information:

https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/iOS

https://parse.com/products/push

http://blog.parse.com/2011/07/18/targeted-push-notifications/

Answer (score 9):

You can save a device id in `ParseInstallation` and then target this installation:

**Receiver:**

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.put("device_id", "1234567890");
installation.saveInBackground();
```

**Sender:**

```
ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery(); 
query.whereEqualTo("device_id", "1234567890");    
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(query);
push.sendPushInBackground();
```

Comment: What do we do when there is no `sendPushInBackground()`?